# Selenium won't type exclamationmarks

Tags: python, selenium

When there's an "!" in the string, the send_keys method from selenium will just skip the exclamationmark.

```
            self.password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name= \"password\"]').send_keys(self.password)
```

The issue isnt caused be the getpass.getpass method.

I tried searching for this issue but couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Are you sure Selenium is skipping the character, and there isn't JavaScript running on the web page that is modifying the value of the password field? Are you sure exclamation marks are one of the allowable characters for passwords at that site?

Comment: Yes i checked both of those things, the only possibility is that selenium is skipping the exclamation mark.

Comment: Which browser are you testing in and its version number? Which web driver and version are you using? Can you post the HTML of the password input as well?